# How to get the gdb GUI to work?

Tags: gdb

I can't figure out how to enable the gdb-gui.

Instead of this:
[image]

I only get this:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/beginner/test/build/unittests/alltest...done.
(gdb)
```

Question: how do I get the gdb GUI to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not have enough reputation to comment, I will post this as an answer.

The [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-User-Interface-Layout.html#GDB-User-Interface-Layout) states:

> To toggle between the many windows layout and a simple layout with just the GUD interaction buffer and a source file, type M-x gdb-many-windows.

Does this help you?